# Convert an expanded html table row to jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a Jquery datatable with rows which expand into another table. The subtable displays perfectly but how do i render this table which is returned by a View into a datatable ?

**Sub table view**

```
@model IEnumerable<Virtual_Machines.Process>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "VM Monitor";
Layout = "";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
var oTable1;

/* Initialize table and make first column non-sortable*/
oTable1 = $('#innerproc').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "aoColumns": [
    { "bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false },
    null,
    null,
    null
    ]
});
</script>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table" id="innerproc">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProcessName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.status)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.date)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>


    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProcessName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.status)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.date)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

As you can see , i tried using javascript to get a reference to the table via id attribute and then convert it to a datatable. This throws an error : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datatable is not a function

I also tried embedding the code in the @section so that it runs when the doc.ready method is called in the main layout file, this too doesn't work. I think i'm not sure as to where to place the code to convert this table to a datatable as it is being returned by a view.

[image: i just want to make the inner table into a datatable]

Comment: Where is mData used?

Comment: did you include datatable.js in html?

Comment: Add this reference - https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

Comment: @diavolic yes its in the _Layout.cshtml

Comment: Any errors in console ?

Comment: try to wrap datatable creating in $(document).ready(). I am sure datatable javascript is not loaded, and your code raises error

Comment: @Harsheet Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datatable is not a function
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2:2620), <anonymous>:4:33)

Comment: @NeuralLynx Try adding refernce to this code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js

Comment: @diavolic datatable jquery plugin is loaded in the Layout.cshtml which is why the 'main table' is successfully being displayed as a datatable. But when i expand the row in this table , the result is a plain html table which is added but not a datatable